# Reading variable number of columns in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a poorly formatted delimited file, in which the there are errors with the delimiter, so it sometimes appears that there are an inconsistent number of columns in different rows.

When I run

```
pd.read_csv('patentHeader.txt', sep="|", header=0)
```

the process dies with this error:

> CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 9 fields in line 1034558, saw 15

Is there a way to have pandas skip these lines and continuing? Or put differently, is there some way to make `read_csv` be more flexible about how many columns it encounters?

Comment: by default `header=0` so you don't need this param unless your intention is that you don't have a header in which case it should be `header=None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
pd.read_csv('patentHeader.txt', sep="|", header=0, error_bad_lines=False)
```

`error_bad_lines`: if False then any lines causing an error will be skipped bad lines, and it will be reported once the reading process is done.